# What should be the best approach for this algorithm? DFS or BFS? and why?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, breadth-first-search

When planting flowers in a pot, it's important to make sure
that whenever you water your plant any water that doesn't
get absorbed by the roots drains out the bottom of the pot.
Otherwise, the water will pool in the bottom of the pot and
cause your plant to rot.

```
You recently decided to plant some flowers of your own,
and decided to fill the base of the pot with gravel. You've
decided to write code to verify whether water will
successfully drain out of the pot.
Using a 2D array to represent your pot, individual pieces of
gravel are notated with a 1 and empty spaces between
gravel are notated with a 0.
Example Pot #1:

[
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
]

Write a function to determine whether the water can fall
from the top row to the bottom, moving through the
spaces between the gravel. Taking the example pot from
above, you can see the posible path, which is marked by
replacing the relevant 0's with asterisks (*)

[
[*, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[*, 1, *, *, *],
[*, *, *, 1, *],
[1, 1, 1, 1, *],
[1, 0, 0, 1, *],
]
```

Notice that the path includes both the top and bottom
rows.
Allowed moves:
The only moves allowed are up, down, left, and right.
Diagonals are not allowed.

```
Here are a few pots that don't drain properly, along with
explanations.

[
[1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
]

Explanation: The top row has no gaps

[
[1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1],
]

Explanation: The bottom row has no gaps
[
[1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 1],
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both solutions work, and both can be implemented using only a constant amount of extra memory, by modifying the matrix in place.  Since the task is to modify the matrix, you might as well take advantage of the ability to do this.

BFS is a little simpler, and will find the shortest path -- not a requirement, but couldn't hurt.

Comment: Got it @Matt thanks, apart from these two approaches. Do you think there is a better approach for this problem? Maybe a complexity of O(n log n)?

Comment: Both approaches take O(n) time.  (where n is rows*cols)  That's the best you could do, since there might be just one path and it might have O(n) steps, and you would have to check them all.

Comment: Does anyone have the solution to this problem would be helpful to learn.